# C# Access Database Remove Rows

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

Hey,
I don't know how to remove a row in Access Database on C#
I know how to add a row:

```
    Database3DataSet.ClientsDataTable Tclients = database3DataSet.Clients;
    Tclients.AddClientsRow(textBox1.Text, textBox2.Text);
```

But I don't know how to remove...
Please help D:

Download link for the Application:
http://uploading.com/files/11b69ce6/WindowsFormsApplication4.rar/
I Realy don't know why it's didn't work...
Can you tell me what's the problem?
Thanks. :)

Comment: `Database3DataSet.ClientsDataTable` doesn't appear to be a public library class. If that is not the case, can you post a link to it's documentation?

Comment: Download link for the Application:
http://uploading.com/files/11b69ce6/WindowsFormsApplication4.rar/
I Realy don't know why it's didn't work...
Can you tell me what's the problem?
Thanks. :)

Comment: I still doמ't understand why the row isn't deleted from the database :(

Comment: Help? :( It's very important to me

Answer (score 1):

There's a `Delete()` method on the DataRow object.

```
Tclients.Rows[0].Delete();
Tclients.AcceptChanges();  // commit the changes
```

Comment: That is what I've done, And nothing happend:
`        private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            Database3DataSet.ClientsDataTable Tclients = database3DataSet.Clients;
            Tclients.Rows[listBox1.SelectedIndex].Delete();
        } `

Comment: You'll need to also call the `AcceptChanges()` method.  [See here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.acceptchanges.aspx)

Comment: Download link for the Application:
http://uploading.com/files/11b69ce6/WindowsFormsApplication4.rar/
I Realy don't know why it's didn't work...
Can you tell me what's the problem?
Thanks. :)

Comment: @Jonas: Have you tried reloading your database after accepting the change? Your application typically does not know to reload on it's own.

Comment: Help? :( It's very important to me